# Error in extremely basic javascript/HTML code

Tags: javascript

So, I have a problem. When I run this code in chrome, it asks me for my name, but if I don't give one, it says "hello null." This is odd, as in my code, I specifically state to pull up a prompt if a name is not entered, and to only print Hello name if name ≠ null. Any ideas?

```
<script>

var name = prompt("What is your name?");

if (name = null) {
    prompt("Please enter your name.");
} else {
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Hello " + name;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `name == null` instead `name = null`

Comment: `(name == null)`

Comment: use if (name == null) instead of if (name = null). In this line, name variable is being assigned with null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prompt cannot be a null prompt can be empty when user click `ok` so you should check like that `if (name === "")` .By the way using `if` condition is not the right solution here. I suggest you change your code like the following.

```
    var name = prompt("What is your name?");
    while (name === "") {
        name = prompt("Please enter your name.");
    }
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Hello " + name;
```

Comment: This worked, thanks

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: This doesn't work, because the `prompt()` method *can* return `null` if the user clicks the cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

With name = null, you're not checking if name is null, you're assigning null to name. Use this instead: if (!name)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and the same error still occurred. Huseyn's suggestion of changing the code to name === "null" worked, however

Comment: Changed my answer, !name will work

Answer (score 0):

Your answer should be

```
<script>

var name = prompt("What is your name?");

if (name) {
    prompt("Please enter your name.");
} else {
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Hello " + name;
}
</script>
```

or you can also use terinary operator:

```
<script>
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
name? prompt("Please enter your name") : document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Hello " + name;
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because the `prompt()` method returns `null` if the user cancels it.

Comment: @nnnnnn try this, if you want to check for null as well then you can do if(name) and that will also check for null pointers.